# can't force redirection to https

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, https

I have a problem with my website at online.net .
I want to force http to use https, but I failed.
In .htacess it didn't do anything when I use th following

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^my-website\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://my-website.com/$1 [R,L]
```

And I get an internal server Error when I try

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

or

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

thanks for any help !

Comment: What apache version are you using, and did you ensure `mod_ssl` and `mod_rewrite` are enabled?

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I got  "Apache/2.4.10 (Ubuntu)", but I don't know about mod_ssl and mod_rewrite.
I just know https://my-website.com it working perfectly fine.

Comment: Then if possible, you should post an answer documenting the steps you took to solve your problem, then mark it as accepted.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
I cheched log error and found "apache2[4]: [core:alert] [pid 4:tid 140433216763648] [client 176.135.210.1:46104] /flex/storage/my-website.com/site/www/.htaccess: RewriteEngine must be On or Off"...

Comment: I asked for support to 1and1 and as a miracle now it works...
thanks for your help !